# Installing ncurses library on windows 8.1

Tags: llvm, ncurses

I am student studying C programming.
I was working on linux environment, but for some reason I have to move my development environment to windows.
I should work with LLVM compiler(I finished installing LLVM on my windows and it seems work). And...Now I need to use ncurses library...How to install it?

Answer (score 1):

Current ncurses has been built with MinGW, MinGW-W64 (Cygwin too, of course) on Windows.  But no one has mentioned LLVM with Windows.  To build ncurses, you need a POSIX shell environment (awk, sed, etc).